# How to broadcast to a multiindex

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multi-index

I have two pandas arrays, A and B, that result from groupby operations. A has a 2-level multi-index consisting of both quantile and date. B just has an index for date.

Between the two of them, the date indices match up (within each quantile index for A).

Is there a standard Pandas function or idiom to "broadcast" B such that it will have an extra level to its multi-index that matches the first multi-index level of A?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do simple arithmetic operations, I think something like `A.div(B, level='date')` should work.

Alternatively, you can do something like `B.reindex(A.index, level='date')` to manually match the indices.

Comment: It's not a simple arithmetic operation, unfortunately. The second suggestion won't work at all because my end result needs to have both of the multi-indices that B has. I have to broadcast a copy of A to all of the sub-groups of B (based on index level 0), do some operations to that resultant thing, and get back a result for each index of B's level-0 multi-index.

Comment: I thought you said A has the MultiIndex and B is a simple Index. If B is the one with a MultiIndex then you can do A.reindex(B.index, level=0), compute the result, and then do result.groupby(level=0) to compute an aggregate result. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want to do though.

Comment: No, you're right. Just flip 'A' and 'B' in my comment. As they are in the question above, they are correct. I just could not edit my comment after 5 minutes. Sorry for the mix up.